# Integrating Ext.ux.touch.Grid with Sencha 2.0

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to display data in some grid view format in Sencha 2.0.When i hunted for this I found

http://www.mindstick.com/Forum/989/Grid%20view%20data%20format%20in%20Sencha%20touch

Sencha Touch does not provide any grid control or any other control to display data in grid format so you have to use the User Extension.

I want to know the steps for integration of Ext.ux.touch.Grid like where to put these file etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Ext.grid.Grid](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Grid) is available since Sencha Touch 2.3.0: Here you can find how to integrate it in your App.

Create a folder `packages` in your main project folder:

[image]

Add the path to `Ext.Loader`:

```
//<debug>
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src',
    'YourAppNamespace': 'app',
    'Ext.ux': './ux',
    'Ext.grid': 'packages/sencha-touch-grid/src/grid'
});
//</debug>
```

And then you can extend it in your application:

```
Ext.define('YourAppNamespace.view.AdvancedGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
    config: { 
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Is it posibble with sencha 2.0

Comment: When i tried to use the grid it throws error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined    List.js"

Comment: Hi, when reviewing edits, such as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3893214), which does improve the post but does not make any effort to fix other glaringly obvious issues with a post, these should be rejected as "too minor", as it takes up too much reviewer time, and it's also rather stupid to fix only one part and leave another bit still not fixed up. For examples, fixing one minor capitalisation issue while not fixing the others would definitely be "too minor". For more information, see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147946). 'Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Ext.grid.Grid is only available if you pay Sencha $4k plus for Sencha Complete or the bundle. It does not come with the 2.x vanilla download...If someone knows otherwise, please post where you find this package, because it is no showing up in my touch src folder. I shart when I saw the $4k price tag...greed will never leave.